# Python extract text after keywords and brackets

Tags: python, regex, text, web-scraping, extract

I am a newbie in python, and after some attempts of searching on the Internet, getting bit confused. What I want to do is the following: extract some information from a website, whose page source contains information below. I would like to extract the lat/long info contained in the brackets in the end: 19.xxxxx, -19.xxxxx.

My idea is to search for myOptions, and then retrieve the coordinates inside brackets. How can I implement this? Thanks!

```
<script>
function initialize() {
    var map, mapOptions, info, i, func, func1, borrar, capa,
        marcador = [], marcadorcalle = [], locales = [], calles = [];

    func = function (num, tipo) {
        return function () {
            if (tipo) {
                info.setContent('<b>' + calles[num][0] + '</b>');
                info.open(map, marcadorcalle[num]);
            } else {
                info.setContent('<b>' + locales[num][0] + '</b><br />' + locales[num][3]);
                info.open(map, marcador[num]);
            }
        };
    };

    func1 = function (objeto, tipo) {
        return function () {
            if (tipo) {
                if (borrar) {borrar.setMap(null); }
                borrar = objeto;
                objeto.setMap(map);
            }
            map.setZoom(18);
            map.setCenter(objeto.getPosition());
            google.maps.event.trigger(objeto, 'click');
        };
    };

    mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        scrollwheel: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.xxxxx, -19.xxxxx)
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where a regular expression would do the job best:

```
import re

map_lat_long = re.compile(r'google\.maps\.LatLng\(([\d.-]+),\s*([\d.-]+)\)')
lat, long = map_lat_long.search(page_source).groups()
```

This assumes that instead of `xxxxx` there are actual digits used. The expression matches the literal `google.maps.LatLng(..)` text, and extracts the two numbers from it by looking for 1 or more digits, dots and dashes each.

Demo (with reduced sample):

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '''\
... mapOptions = {
...     zoom: 16,
...     scrollwheel: false,
...     center: new google.maps.LatLng(19.12345, -19.67890)
... };
... '''
>>> map_lat_long = re.compile(r'google\.maps\.LatLng\(([\d.-]+),\s*([\d.-]+)\)')
>>> map_lat_long.search(sample).groups()
('19.12345', '-19.67890')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The sample works great! But I tried to retrieve the page source through source_page=requests.get(url), then when I use your code here, I get an error: TypeError: expected string or buffer
What does this mean?

Comment: @ximu: you have a response object, not text. Use `source_page.content` to get the (undecoded) page source.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It works. Just wondering, can I put re.compile(r'center: \new\google\.maps\.LatLng\(([\d.-]+),\s*([\d.-]+)\)'), I tried to run this, and it gives AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'.

Comment: @ximu: that means your pattern is incorrect and nothing was matched. Use `r'center: new google\.maps\.LatLng\(([\d.-]+),\s*([\d.-]+)\)'` instead.

Comment: @ximu: try out patterns on an online regular expression editor first maybe. Here is a Regex101 link for the updated pattern so you can play with it: https://regex101.com/r/nX0tD8/1